# Move publish date of all wordpress posts back by one day

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, bitnami

I have deployed a Bitnami AWS stack for Wordpress and the site seems to be functioning fine. Unfortunately, I miscalculated the publish date for around 40 posts. I need to update all these posts (either already published or scheduled) to move the publish date back by one day. All bulk edit plugins I could find only allow post dates to be set to a particular value, they don't seem to provide a way to alter the dates using a delta calculation (e.g. -1 day in my case).

Is there a way to update the dates either using the MySQL database or PHP? I do have SSH access to the wordpress deployment.

Comment: `UPDATE a_table SET the_date_col = DATE_SUB(the_date_col, INTERVAL 1 DAY) WHERE a_indexed_col_preferably IN( 1,2,3,4,5,6.....)`

Comment: Honest answer: yes, but it would probably be easier to just edit them by hand (40's not that many).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a backup first and execute this SQL query to update all posts' dates, I disabled strict mode because MySQL 5.7 doesn't accept zeros in dates anymore so it'll be ignored:

```
SET sql_mode = '';

update wp_posts
set 
post_date = DATE_ADD(post_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY),
post_date_gmt = DATE_ADD(post_date_gmt , INTERVAL -1 DAY);
```

For scheduled posts you can use [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post/) action but you should tweak it for new posts if not scheduled.